# Using Python Interactively as a CLI calculator

Tags: command-line, python

I'm running Ubuntu 14.10 & I'm totally new to Python.

I'm aware that Python can be used as a CLI type calculator in interactive mode, a bit like the bc command in Bash.

I have two questions:

1. how to set the number of decimal places for answers to calculations
2. what do I need to do to be able to use mathematical functions like `sqrt`, `sin`, `arcos`, `log`

Whenever I try to use any of these function I get an error message, such as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

NameError: name 'sin' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) how to set the number of decimal places for answers to calculations

For floating point operations (in python2) you have to use float numbers instead of integers, see:

```py
>>> 3/2
1
>>> 3/2.0
1.5
>>> 3.0/2
1.5
```

If you are using python3, then the result is floating, even of both operands are integers:

```py
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct  8 2014, 13:08:17) [GCC 4.9.1] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 3/2
1.5
>>> 3/3
1.0
```

To perform integer division in python3, use `//` operator:

```py
>>> 3//2
1
>>> 3//3
1
```

> 2) what do I need to do to be able to use mathematical functions like sqrt, sin, arcos, log

Those functions live in the math module, the simplest way to have them available is:

```py
>>> from math import *
>>> sqrt(4)
2.0
```

Be careful though, as it may pollute your namespace (if there are variables or functions with the same names as in `math` module). It is safer to use:

```py
>>> import math
>>> math.sqrt(4)
2.0
```

Comment: 1) is not true anymore if using `python3`...

Comment: @Rmano, thanks for the observation, I edited my answer to address your feedback. Thanks!